# Elementor Different Background Colors

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor

I've broke my head trying to solve my problem but unfortunately I still didn't find the correct solution.

All I want is to have the white background to the left of the Column#1 and the grey background to the right of the Column#2.

But I can't find the needed attribute in the Column options (and I'm not sure if there are any.

I've attached the hand draw of what I want to do.

Thanks guys, you're the best.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Set the background of the section as Gradient.
2. Select White as 1st color
3. Select Gray as your 2nd color
4. Set Gradient type = Linear
5. Set Angel to 90
6. Now Adjust the Location as per your liking (15+ recommended)
7. Click the link below to see the result I have got.

[You will see something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMxBM.png)

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this pretty easily by using a pseudo-element for the grey background. On your body set a white background.

```css
body {
    background: #fff;
    }
    main {
    position: relative;
    height: 250px;
    }
    main::after {
    content: '';
    background: grey;
    position: absolute;
    width: 35%;
    height: 100%;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    }
    main .container {
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
    }
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
    
    </header>
    <main>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="column1">
        
        </div>
        <div class="column2">
        
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
    <footer>
    
    </footer>
</body>
```